# aligning two span classes in one row

Tags: jquery, html, css

So..I've created some forms that my users can fill out and upload some doc files to. The issue that i am having is when my users upload their files the attachment name appears as well as a X button to delete the upload. Right now everything comes up but the X and the doc name are not lined up correctly but in two separate lines and i was wondering if someone can help me out with this issue.

```css
.ui-icon, .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
}
.ui-icon {
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
}
.ui-icon {
display: block;
text-indent: -99999px;
overflow: hidden;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.blueArea {
color: #2795b6;
padding: 5px;
}
.blueArea {
line-height: 29px;
padding: 0 5px 10px !important;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
.greyArea {
color: #C0C0C0;
}
.greyArea {
line-height: 25px;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <input type="checkbox" name="j_id0:formId:j_id162:0:j_id166" checked="checked" class="015g0000000CTPOAA4" style="display:none;">
 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" onclick="unselect('015g0000000CTPOAA4')"></span>
 <span class="blueArea">"seal.png"</span>
 <span class="greyArea">"29 KB"</span>
<div>
```

Comment: You're not using vertical-align correctly. It needs to be applied to an element with "display:table-cell;" whose parent element must be set at "display:table;". I also don;t understand why you set a checkbox with display set to "none". There is also no value parameter. You should be using input type="hidden" that has a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is one element (the X, probably) is display:block. Set it to display:inline-block; in your CSS and it should work fine.

Comment: Just to add to this, Spans are generally for text and therefore margin and padding don't work until you override this behaviour by setting the display:block. Thereby making it behave like a div

Comment: hmmm ok then should i just make the X a div instead of a span?

Comment: I'd say leave it as a span for the meantime. Spans are meant for inline items (i.e. you want a word in a sentence to be red, so you wrap it with a span) whereas divs are meant for block items (i.e. an item that you want to wrap something else or an item that is meant to go on its own line). A very basic explanation, there's more to it than that, but I think that's the basic idea )